# RPi3 as access point: How to execute a bash script every time a new connection is established

Tags: pi-3, wifi, server, accessibility

I use an RPI3 as a standalone access point (following [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md) tutorial) and I would like to make it execute a bash script when a device is connected to its wireless network. What is the appropriate way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By searching I found a solution.

Step 1: Create a file named onHostapdChange.sh

```
nano onHostapdChange.sh
```

Step 2: In the file type or copy-paste the lines...

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $2 == "AP-STA-CONNECTED" ]]
then
  echo "someone has connected with mac id $3 on $1"
fi

if [[ $2 == "AP-STA-DISCONNECTED" ]]
then
  echo "someone has disconnected with mac id $3 on $1"
fi
```

... then save (Ctrl + O) and exit nano (Ctrl + X).

Step 3. Make it executable:

```
chmod +x onHostapdChange.sh
```

Step 4. Execute the command

```
sudo hostapd_cli -a '/onHostapdChange.sh'
```

If the error message '*Failed to connect to hostapd - wpa_ctrl_open: No such file or directory*' appears then edit the file '/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf'...

```
sudo nano /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
```

...in the end of the file append the lines:

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/hostapd
ctrl_interface_group=0
```

...and restart the service:

```
sudo systemctl stop hostapd
sudo systemctl start hostapd
```

Instructions (combined) from

1. https://superuser.com/questions/1071354/hostapd-execute-a-command-when-there-is-new-connection-established
2. https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=63045